# Does anybody know how to implement a Timeline Chart or Event Chart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I need to implement a Timeline chart in Flutter. How do I do it?

I have tried to use charts_flutter library. However, it does not include Timeline chart.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `charts_flutter: ^0.6.0` it works great with time series, I don't understand the idea of a Timeline chart, in case of needing a timeline I wouldn't recommend a chart library.

If a Timeseries chart is ok for you here is the example I used:
[Flutter Time Series Charts Example](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/simple)

Talking about Timelines explicit, you can have a look to this package: [Flutter Timeline Widget](https://pub.dev/packages/timeline_list)

Comment: What exactly I am trying to present in my project is to show state of power (ON and OFF) with precise duration and time the power ON and OFF. Example : x-range chart https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/x-range-series

Comment: Like Gantt Chart but x-axis should contain hours.